# Exporting a non-ideal list format to Excel

Tags: python, excel, list, export, export-to-excel

I have a large list, contains a series of ids and related values, extremely shortened version looks like so:

```
large = [('550111', [(4, 5, 8), (6, -4, -6)]), ('222211', [(2, -4, 5), (1, 15, -4)])]
```

I want to export this to excel in a way that `5501` will be in `A1`, then the first set of values will be under it in `B1`, `B2` & `B3` and the next set in `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, then have a space then `2222` in `E1`, with the first set of values relating to it in `F1`, `F2` & `F3`, the second in `G1`, `G2`, `G3`. i.e. in Excel (every value with its own Excel rectangle thing to itself) like:

```
550111
4 5 8
6 -4 -6
'space here (dont know how to add one)'
222211
2 -4 5
1 15 -4
'SPACE HERE AGAIN'
```

I have tried the follwoing:

```
writer_jobby = csv.writer(open('poo5.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',')

for i in large:

    if i == '[':

        i.replace()

    if i == ']':

        i.replace()

    if i == '(':

        i.replace()

    if i == ')':

        i.replace()

    else:

        writer_jobby.writerow(i)
```

But I get absolute nonsense, as I am struggling with how to deal with the `[]` and the `()` in my list.  I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on how I could deal with the data so I could export it in the desired way.  Thank you.

Help much appreciated.

***EDIT***

new desired form incl. **absolute max**:

```
550111
4,5,8 
6,-4,-6
'space here'
'Max:'
6, 5, 8
'space here'     
222211 
2,-4,5 
1,15,-4
'space here'
'Max:'
2, 15, 5 
'space here'
1, 2, 3, ........, 8904
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help?

```
import csv
large = [('5501', [(4, 5, 8), (6, -4, -6)]), ('2222', [(2, -4, 5), (1, 15, -4)])]

with open("out1.csv", "wb") as fp: # open the file, call it fp, and autoclose it
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=",")
    for entry in large:
        writer.writerow([entry[0]]) # one-element list
        for line in entry[1]: # loop over each tuple in the second element
            writer.writerow(line)
        writer.writerow([]) # write an empty row
```

This produces

```
localhost-2:coding $ cat out1.csv 
5501
4,5,8
6,-4,-6

2222
2,-4,5
1,15,-4
```

The `csv` module is typically used by writing rows from elements.  I don't know what `final` is, but it looks like you're trying to do something with a string made from `large`, which isn't going to work very well.

Comment: oh and 'final' and 'large' were the same thing I forgot to change the name

Comment: any suggestion as to how I could add the word 'Max' after the space at the end of each set of values and underneath it add in the the maxs from each above, then another space...also after the very lasy space adding the numbers 1 to 8904?  Please see my edit above

Comment: @user1532369: if you have a separate (and very different) question, then please open a new question and don't edit this one.  SO questions work best when they're discrete and specific.

Comment: @user1532369: no worries.  But I'd give your new problem a go yourself first-- one of the first questions you'll get is "what have you tried?"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904832/modifying-a-non-ideal-list-format-to-excel-and-exporting-it I have but I do not know how to apply max and absolute functions to the indiviual values inside the list